# Upgrade mcrypt to OpenSSL encryption in SagePay gateway form

Tags: openssl, opayo

Currently we have mcyrpt encryption in our SagePay gateway form, which isn't available or supported in PHP 7.4.

Would anyone have any idea on how we can change the code below from mcyrpt to OpenSSL:

```
    // AES encryption, CBC blocking with PKCS5 padding then HEX encoding.
    // Add PKCS5 padding to the text to be encypted.
    $string = self::addPKCS5Padding($string);

    // Perform encryption with PHP's MCRYPT module.
    $crypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $key);

    // Perform hex encoding and return.
    return "@" . strtoupper(bin2hex($crypt));
}

/**
 * Decode a returned string from SagePay.
 *
 * @param string $strIn         The encrypted String.
 * @param string $password      The encyption password used to encrypt the string.
 *
 * @return string The unecrypted string.
 * @throws SagepayApiException
 */
static public function decryptAes($strIn, $password)
{
    // HEX decoding then AES decryption, CBC blocking with PKCS5 padding.
    // Use initialization vector (IV) set from $str_encryption_password.
    $strInitVector = $password;

    // Remove the first char which is @ to flag this is AES encrypted and HEX decoding.
    $hex = substr($strIn, 1);

    // Throw exception if string is malformed
    if (!preg_match('/^[0-9a-fA-F]+$/', $hex))
    {
        throw new SagepayApiException('Invalid encryption string');
    }
    $strIn = pack('H*', $hex);

    // Perform decryption with PHP's MCRYPT module.
    $string = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $password, $strIn, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $strInitVector);
    return self::removePKCS5Padding($string);
}
```

Below is the OpenSSL code that we're trying out, but it needs some tweaking, any suggestions on what we need to change to get the OpenSSL code to replace the above mcyrpt would be very much appreciated!

Comment: [`mcrypt_encrypt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) and [`openssl_encrypt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) are described in detail as well as their respective counterparts for decryption, so it should be possible to port the code from _mcrypt_ to _openssl_. If you've migrated the code and then get stuck, please post your code and describe the problem.

Comment: Good Evening, Many thanks for your reply. Below is the OpenSSL code that we are trying out, but stuck trying to tweak the code to get it work properly. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated:

Comment: function encrypt_openssl($msg, $key, $iv = null) {
 $iv_size = openssl_cipher_iv_length('AES-128-CBC');
 if (!$iv) {
  $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($iv_size);
 }
 $encryptedMessage = openssl_encrypt($msg, 'AES-128-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
 return base64_encode($iv . $encryptedMessage);
}
function decrypt_openssl($payload, $key) {
 $raw = base64_decode($payload);
 $iv_size = openssl_cipher_iv_length('AES-128-CBC');
 $iv = substr($raw, 0, $iv_size);
 $data = substr($raw, $iv_size);
 return openssl_decrypt($data, 'AES-128-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
}

Comment: We're able to get through to the SagePay gateway with the above OpenSSL code, but we get an error, which looks like it's to do with the SagePay website not being able to communicate back with our website.

Answer (score 0):

The posted *openssl* code works, i.e. a plaintext encrypted with `encrypt_openssl` can be decrypted with `decrypt_openssl`. However, the *openssl* code is not functionally identical to the *mcrypt* code, i.e. data encrypted with the *mcrypt* code cannot be decrypted with the *openssl* code and vice versa.

I'm not quite clear about the workflow, but I suspect that the encryption and decryption logic of the *mcrypt* code is also used by the SagePay gateway, so it is necessary for communication that the `openssl` code is functionally identical to the `mcrypt` code (although the implementation of the `openssl` code is more secure than the *mcrypt* code).

Unfortunately important parts of the code were not posted, e.g. the encryption method is incomplete, `addPKCS5Padding` and `removePKCS5Padding` are missing completely, so that partly assumptions must be worked with.

Regarding the *mcrypt* code applies:

- AES-128 is used in CBC mode. AES-128 requires a 16 bytes key.
- As IV the key is used. Note that this is generally insecure, [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/16161).
- *mcrypt* itself applies implicitly Zero padding in the variant that no padding is performed if the length of the plaintext already corresponds to an integer multiple of the blocksize. Since a customized padding with PKCS5 (actually PKCS7) is done first, the *mcrypt* padding does not take effect, so that effectively PKCS5 padding is applied. Unfortunately the implementations of *addPKCS5Padding* and *removePKCS5Padding* were not posted, so it is not possible to check if they both comply with the standard. After decryption the PKCS5 padding is removed (unlike the built in Zero padding from *mcrypt*).
- The encryption performs a hex encoding of the ciphertext using upper case letters and prefixes it with `@`.

With regard to *openssl* the following has to be considered:

- *openssl* uses PKCS7 padding by default (which is removed by default during decryption), which is functionally identical to the padding used in the *mcrypt* code (at least if the custom PKCS5 padding used in the *mcrypt* code matches the standard).
- `openssl_encrypt` returns the ciphertext Base64 encoded by default (and *openssl_decrypt* expects it in this encoding as well). The flag `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` causes *openssl_encrypt* to return the data as raw data (and *openssl_decrypt* expects raw data as well)

The following *openssl* implementations are functionally identical to the *mcrypt* implementations within the scope of the assumptions made. A 16 bytes key must be used:

```
function encrypt_openssl($msg, $key, $iv) { 
    $encryptedMessage = openssl_encrypt($msg, 'AES-128-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv); 
    return '@' . strtoupper(bin2hex($encryptedMessage));
} 

function decrypt_openssl($encMsg, $key, $iv) { 
    $encMsg = substr($encMsg, 1);
    // your validation stuff
    $encMsg = hex2bin($encMsg);
    return openssl_decrypt($encMsg, 'AES-128-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv); 
}
```

**EDIT:**

The two methods `addPKCS5Padding` and `removePKCS5Padding` comply with the PKCS7 standard. A modification is not necessary. These functions must not be used in the *openssl* functions, because *openssl* implicitly uses PKCS7 padding, so it would be padded twice, which would result in a different ciphertext.

That the encryption of the *SagePay* code matches the encryption of the *openssl* functions I posted can be easily tested:

Encryption with the *SagePay* code (the code can be executed e.g. [here](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) selecting V 7.0.x or below):

```
<?php
class SagepayApiException extends Exception {}

class SagePayTest {

    static public function encryptAes($string, $key)
    {
        $string = self::addPKCS5Padding($string);
        $crypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $key);
        return "@" . strtoupper(bin2hex($crypt));
    }
    
    static public function decryptAes($strIn, $password)
    {
        $strInitVector = $password;
        $hex = substr($strIn, 1);
        if (!preg_match('/^[0-9a-fA-F]+$/', $hex))
        {
            throw new SagepayApiException('Invalid encryption string');
        }
        $strIn = pack('H*', $hex);
        $string = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $password, $strIn, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $strInitVector);
        return self::removePKCS5Padding($string);
    }
    static protected function addPKCS5Padding($input)
    {
        $blockSize = 16;
        $padd = "";
        $length = $blockSize - (strlen($input) % $blockSize);
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $length; $i++)
        {
            $padd .= chr($length);
        }
        return $input . $padd;
    }
    static protected function removePKCS5Padding($input)
    {
        $blockSize = 16;
        $padChar = ord($input[strlen($input) - 1]);
        if ($padChar > $blockSize)
        {
            throw new SagepayApiException('Invalid encryption string');
        }
        if (strspn($input, chr($padChar), strlen($input) - $padChar) != $padChar)
        {
            throw new SagepayApiException('Invalid encryption string');
        }
        $unpadded = substr($input, 0, (-1) * $padChar);
        if (preg_match('/[[:^print:]]/', $unpadded))
        {
            throw new SagepayApiException('Invalid encryption string');
        }
        return $unpadded;
    }
}

$plaintext = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
$testkey = "95tjbs763khd9zh7";
$encrypted = SagePayTest::encryptAes($plaintext, $testkey);
$decrypted = SagePayTest::decryptAes($encrypted, $testkey);
print("Ciphertext (hex): " . $encrypted . PHP_EOL);
print("Decrypted  (hex):  " . bin2hex($decrypted) . PHP_EOL);
print("Decrypted       :  " . $decrypted . PHP_EOL);
?>
```

Output:

```
Ciphertext (hex): @67D4D4E0019BA7D0E75CC92C41488EF13613C1ED8A95B60E56347D1514AC5D7AF780F4314CA047A487AB67DF2D94174A
Decrypted  (hex):  54686520717569636b2062726f776e20666f78206a756d7073206f76657220746865206c617a7920646f67
Decrypted       :  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Encryption with the *openssl* functions (the code can be executed e.g. [here](https://paiza.io/en/projects/new?language=php)):

```
<?php
function encrypt_openssl($msg, $key, $iv) { 
    $encryptedMessage = openssl_encrypt($msg, 'AES-128-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv); 
    return '@' . strtoupper(bin2hex($encryptedMessage));
} 

function decrypt_openssl($encMsg, $key, $iv) { 
    $encMsg = substr($encMsg, 1);
    // your validation stuff
    $encMsg = hex2bin($encMsg);
    return openssl_decrypt($encMsg, 'AES-128-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv); 
}

$plaintext = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
$testkey = "95tjbs763khd9zh7";
$encrypted = encrypt_openssl($plaintext, $testkey, $testkey);
$decrypted = decrypt_openssl($encrypted, $testkey, $testkey);
print("Ciphertext (hex): " . $encrypted . PHP_EOL);
print("Decrypted  (hex):  " . bin2hex($decrypted) . PHP_EOL);
print("Decrypted       :  " . $decrypted . PHP_EOL);
?>
```

Output:

```
Ciphertext (hex): @67D4D4E0019BA7D0E75CC92C41488EF13613C1ED8A95B60E56347D1514AC5D7AF780F4314CA047A487AB67DF2D94174A
Decrypted  (hex):  54686520717569636b2062726f776e20666f78206a756d7073206f76657220746865206c617a7920646f67
Decrypted       :  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Both encryptions and decryptions match.

Comment: Many thanks for all the information that you have provided. It's very much appreciated! Not sure if we need to remove / tweak the addPKCS5Padding / removePKCS5Padding? Below is a link to the whole SagePay file, the encryption part starts at line 567. Any further information would be greatly appreciated:                     https://github.com/wp-e-commerce/Gold-Cart/blob/master/merchants/sagepay.php                     Kind Regards, Andy

Comment: @Andy - Regarding the encryption / decryption no further changes should be necessary, see the edit section of my answer.

Comment: Many thanks for sending through such detailed information. It's been greatly appreciated! You've been very helpful. I can see from your examples that the encryptions and decryptions match, but for some reason when I apply the openssl code to the SagePay file; I'm still getting the same error. Not sure if there is something simple that I have overlooked or missed? Kind Regards, Andy

Comment: @Andy - Since the encryption with _openssl_ has been shown to provide the same ciphertext as the one with _mcrypt_, this can actually be excluded as the cause of the problem. Another possibility could be that _openssl_ is not enabled. The linked PHP code also checks for _mcrypt_ whether the corresponding module is enabled (lines 160-168). For the enabling of _openssl_ see e.g. [here](https://faq.miniorange.com/knowledgebase/enable-php-openssl-extension/), but it could be of course more complex depending on your environment.

Comment: Thanks again for all your amazing help and support. I can confirm that openssl is enabled. As you mentioned we can rule out the openssl code that you have provided, as this works from from what you have shown on your example. I'm going to do further investigating through the code to see if I can spot anything that maybe the cause. One last question, do I need to delete any of this code in the SagePay file that mentions static protected function addPKCS5Padding($input)
    {static protected function removePKCS5Padding($input)  $string = self::addPKCS5Padding($string); Kind Regards, Andy

Comment: As I understood it, the _mcrypt_ logic in `encryptAes()` / `decryptAes()` shall be replaced by the _openssl_ logic. Since in the current code `removePKCS5Padding()` is only used in `decryptAes()` and `addPKCS5Padding()` only in `encryptAes()` and furthermore the _openssl_ logic does not need both functions (_openssl_ pads _implicitly_ with PKCS5 / PKCS7), both functions can be deleted (but nothing should happen if they are still present).

Comment: Thanks again. Really appreciate all your help and advise. Kind Regards, Andy

Comment: Sorry to trouble you again. I've got one last question. The 2 errors that I'm seeing that are preventing the SagePay file from working are: undefined index: state in sagepay.php on line 263 - code relating to this is: $strBillingState       = $this->cleanInput( $billInfo['state'], WPSC_SAGEPAY_CLEAN_INPUT_FILTER_TEXT);        and the other error is: indefined index: payment_type in sagepay.php on line 440, code relating to this: <input type="hidden" name="TxType" value ="' . wpec_sagepay_validate_payment_type( $this->sagepay_options['payment_type'] ) . '"  ></input>          Kind Regards, Andy

Comment: I'm really sorry, but unfortunately I don't see any connection here with the changes made to the encryption.

Comment: Hey no worries. Thanks again for all your help!